# Picture is in the wrong orientation

Tags: android

I want to draw an image to an imageview just for testing out things, but the problem is that the image gets drawn in landscape, even though it is a portrait picture. Does anybody know how I can "force" it to be drawn in portrait mode?

```
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);


    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test.jpg");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
    //Bitmap fbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), m, false);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

I tried to flip the image, but when I try to save the current bitmap into the fbitmap i get a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Does anybody know whats up with the error and how I can fix the image? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `postRotate()` method:

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test.jpg");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.postRotate(90); //postRotate(angle of rotation)
Bitmap fbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), m, true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

And in the manifest under `<application>` tags add:

```
android:largeHeap = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [setRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float)) method of ImageView

Comment: Well that semi worked..it is in the right orientation now, but the picture isn't full screen. Its like a mini version of the original picture